# Brightness Indicator

Tags: windows-7, brightness

What software can I use for Windows 7 to show an on-screen progress-bar notification of the brightness when I change the brightness of my screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest downloading this: [GrowlForWindows](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/default.aspx), and then downloading this [addon](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/displays/meter) for it. If you need help with this, I suggest either commenting on my answer or visiting [this](http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/help/default.aspx) site.

Comment: if you are using the same link in more than one place, it *should* allow you to use the syntax I used in the edit.

Comment: That was another link to another part of the site. Not the same one. The one you made was to http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/default.aspx. The one I posted was to http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/help/default.aspx. there's a /help/ in there.

Comment: My apologies, fixed

Comment: Thanks. Though I am now able to do that by myself lol. At the time of writing I was at 1 rep. Again, thanks anyway.

Comment: What else do I need? I appears that those two downloads alone are not enough. I need some way of making windows trigger Growl...

Answer (score 2):

If it is a Dell laptop, install the version of Dell QuickSet which is compatible with your laptop.